# IGBT not switching on with a diode in connection

Tags: diodes, power-electronics, igbt

[image]

Hi, I am trying to switch on/off a IGBT (CM1000HA-28H) to control a current. The IGBT is driven by a driver board ([Powerex BG1A board](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1682847.pdf)). A problem we encounter is that if a diode ([SD600](https://www.galco.com/techdoc/vish/sd600n04pc_dat.pdf)) is connected in the loop like in the figure, the IGBT does not close, whereas if we remove the diode in the loop, the IGBT closes and opens in response to a TTL signal. This has been a vexing problem, because the circuit as drawn *used to* work, but after resoldering our driver board, it only partially works as I have described. What could have gone wrong?

EDIT: I discovered that if I put multimeter probes across the collector and the emitter on ohmmeter mode, the IGBT closes and the current passes through the diode. But if I turn off and on the TTL again, there is no current so I would have to re-apply this trick. The probe polarity doesn't matter, and multimeter on voltmeter mode doesn't work.

Also, when the current flows the diode, the power supply has to push a higher current than it normally should. The forward voltage drop of the unconnected diode measured by my multimeter is 0.3V. Without the diode, the power supply runs at (0.7V, 0.5A through the load. With the diode and the trick applied, the supply runs at (1.3V, 0.5A). The increase in the voltage is due to the diode - I measured voltage drop of 0.6V across the connected diode, which is more than the voltage drop measured when it was unconnected. What is going on?

Comment: The TTL input signal is referenced to what point in your circuit?

Comment: @gcr, the TTL ground is connected to the power supply ground that powers the TTL inverter + IGBT driver. If you click the spec sheet linked to "Powerex BG1A board" the wirings become clear.

Comment: Whatever it is, this is defenetly not a schematic.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by the gate of the IGBT not being driven hard enough. We used a 33 ohm resistor for the gate resistance (this is the maximum recommended value according to the BG1A circuit board datasheet) - lowering it to 10 ohm solved the issue.